# runserver must be manually restarted after error in models.py

Tags: django

I'm following the book The Definitive Guide to Django and one thing I've started noticing is that whenever I make a single error in my models file, the server just hangs and is not automatically restarted when the error is fixed.

Here's an example: I save the file with a line like this

```
email = models.EmailField(blank=Tru)
```

Which raises the obvious error and stack trace

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.core.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x00000000025B0400>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 91, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 64, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\....\models.py", line 17, in <module>
    class Author(models.Model):
  File "C:\...\models.py", line 20, in Author
    email = models.EmailField(blank=Tru)
NameError: name 'Tru' is not defined
```

Now, if I change `Tru` to `True`, the server does not restart. Is this intentional? Or is there something wrong with my application? I've just started learning Django so I have no idea if this is common behaviour.

I'm on Windows, running Python 2.7.3 and Django 1.4.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not just you- I also experience this on occasion.

Although the development server is usually pretty good about restarting after code changes, some particularly egregious errors (especially in your `models.py`) can sometimes cause it to hang. Just need to terminate it (`Ctrl+C`), restart it, and continue along your merry way.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I can `CTRL+C`, it's just that having to do that every single time I make a mistake is kind of annoying. I'll accept your answer if there really is nothing I can do about this. I'd like to ask another question though. Is this problem most egregious in the `models.py` file? Does the server restart with other files? Or should I be expecting this all the time with Django?

Comment: The development server generally restarts successfully to changes to urls, views, and changes to models.py that don't contain syntax errors.

Comment: This seems to still be an issue. It is disappointing that the server does not restart itself after any error.

Comment: This also happens to me in production mode, is this normal?